# Visual studio Xamarin android button click event code generation

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, button

Hello I am trying to figure out how to create the code for what happens when a button is click in windows form i just double click the button and it generates the code for the button but I am lost I saw a guy on YouTube type this in her but its not generating any code for me?[image: what do i do]

how do I go about generating this? I am new to android gui development.

Thanks for your time.
steven

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?
[image]

If so, just open your ToolBox,search the `Button` control, Double click the Button, it will generate it.

[image]